# What version of season 14 PvP gear should I focus on for a lvl 90 Holy Priest?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Holy/Shadow
lvl 90 Undead
Server Arthas

I am returning to the World of Warcraft after several years. Many, many things have changed in the game and I am hopelessly trying to play catch-up. Most importantly is getting up to snuff as a PvP healer. So far, all I manage to do is tickle my teammates with my heals. I have looked into Tyrannical Gladiator pieces, but I've noticed there are quite a few changes to attributes.

I usually queue up for random battlegrounds as I want to maximize the frequency of getting into one.
I tend to heal more with AoE with [Chakra: Sanctuary] enabled.

Comment: Buy contender gear(crafter PvP gear) on the Auction house, then farm BG's for Hounor with the hounor buy tyranical gear when you are full Tyranical start arena and get full new gear,

Comment: Just bought 3 pieces of Contender, already seeing a major boost in stats. Thank you very much for the response!

Comment: Made the comment into a answer as you where happy with it. Made the comment to aid all the other people who might find this question

Comment: Welcome to [gaming.se]. Like other Stack Exchange sites, when your question is answered to your satisfaction, you should mark your question as solved by clicking the check mark next to the answer that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you just came back to WoW there is a certain route you can take to getting up to scratch with gear, It's a 3 step process.

### Step One

Go to the AH and buy a full set of **Contender Gear(crafted PvP gear)**

### Step Two

Queue for BGs and farm honor until you have full Tyranical Season 13 gear(24k Honor roughly)

### Step Three

Queue for Arena and start getting your 3-5k cap and buy s14 gear with. Once you start getting s14 gear you are up to date with most players who are gearing still. I don't think it's possible to be fully geared yet but as I am not doing PvP this season, I'm not sure.

Comment: At this point I'd sooner buy Crafted Malevolent gear, as it doesn't look like the Contender's gear was scaled up.

Comment: I don't think you can buy crafted Malevolent gear.

Comment: Why not? It's all BoE and tailors, LW and blacksmiths make it.